# meaning of preposition "for" in "sing for joy"

Tags: prepositions

I have read the following sentence:

They drink and sing for joy.

What does that mean? Are they so happy that they sing to celebrate it?

Comment: More properly, there are only four people, and it's "sing 4 joy".

Comment: The same thing it means in "jump for joy," which is *because of*.

Comment: See also [ell.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  ***[for](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)*** means:

​

> because of or as a result of something:
>
> - I'm feeling all the better for my holiday.
> - "How are you?" "Fine, and all the better for seeing you!"

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Usage etymology:

> ***[For](https://www.etymonline.com/word/for)*** alone as a conjunction, "because, since, for the reason that; in order that" is from late Old English, probably a shortening of common Old English phrases such as for þon þy "therefore," literally "for the (reason) that.

(Etymonline)

Comment: A person can hang their head for shame.

Comment: Whoa! The OP is expected to do that homework, though.